# Linked List Implementation of a stack in C++

Tags: c++, oop, syntax, linked-list, stack

So I guess my question is a bit noobish but we've just started linked lists, stacks and queues and I'm feeling a bit lost in terms of syntax.

I have a working linked list structure with adding to back and front, pushing, popping, deleting etc.. but I get crazy lost when it comes to calling those functions in the stack implementation. The Linked List class declaration is in a header file with function definitions in a .cpp file. The stack is exactly the same story. We have been given the header file with function declarations and we need to write our own definitions in a separate .cpp file.

My problem lies in calling the linked list functions in the stack functions. The stack includes an "LList data" (the linked list structure is called LList); a pointer to an integer (I'm assuming) "int *data" and and integer tracking the top of the stack "int t"

The funcitons we have to write are the constructor, destructor, pop, push and size functions. I'd give source code but it really isn't anything significant to work with at all.

I hope my question can be understood >_<
Thanks in advance
Cameron

Comment: You haven't actually described what the problem is...

Comment: I basically don't know where to start when it comes to defining the given stack functions and I don't know how to call the already existing linked list functions in the stack function definition file

Comment: If you already have a working linked list, it would seem that you only have to have pushing at the back and popping from the back to treat it as a stack. Without seeing the code you have, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Sorry, your question is too broad, please clarify it.

Comment: If given an integer, "value", to push to the stack, how would you call the Linked List function "push_front(Value)" in the stack function definition of the push function?

Answer (score 1):

A stack is just a linked list with different interface functions. You only need to be able to `push` elements to the "top" of the stack, and `pop` from the top.

It looks like your `Stack` class implementation is designed to be a wrapper around the `LList` class you already have.

Without going into the details (which is kinda hard without looking at the code),

1. You have a `Stack` class with a `LList` as a member variable (preferably private).
2. Your `push` function should simply insert to the tail of your linked list.
3. Your `pop` function should remove the last element from the tail of your linked list
4. Your `~Stack` implementation should delete the `LList` object you created; you can skip this if you use smart pointers, or use the `delete` keyword if you manually created an object using `new`.

More code will help refine this answer.

Comment: I think that `~LList` shouldn't be called manually - it's called automatically just before object is deleted. Calling d-tor manually when it's not designed to allow it may cause errors.